# How to pass two parameters to dashDB query element of Node-Red from IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, dashdb

I'm trying to pass two parameters into sql query from dashDB object in Node-Red flow editor on Bluemix. My parameters are stored in msg.fromDate and msg.toDate and I want to enter them into "Parameter Marker" of dashDB node. When I only use one parameter, I simply type **"msg.fromDate"** in Parameter Markers and it works fine. In log I see this:

> 2015-12-10T12:22:12.856+0100 [App/0] out Input node: pathToArray:
>   **msg,toDate** 2015-12-10T12:22:12.856+0100 [App/0] out Input node: parameterValues: **2015-12-01**

Now, when I try to use two input parameters I type **"msg.toDate, msg.fromDate"** in "Parameter Marker" I'm getting this error in log:

> 2015-12-10T12:26:01.271+0100 [App/0] out 10 Dec 11:26:01 - [error]
>   [dashDB in:popular words] TypeError: **Cannot read property 'fromDate'
>   of undefined**
>
> 2015-12-10T12:26:01.270+0100 [App/0] out Input node: pathToArray:
>   **msg,toDate, msg,fromDate**

How to pass two parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason for this issue. It looks that when I enter "Parameter Marker" like this:

```
msg.toDate, msg.fromDate
```

it does not work. And like this it works:

```
msg.toDate,msg.fromDate
```

In other words space between parameters breaks it!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have quotes between the parameters, not sure if you add quotes just to format your quest or actually added it to your parameters.

I wrote a simple node-red flow with `function node` to build the query and the `dashDB node` itself.

In my `function node` I have the following query:

```
msg.fromDate = '2011-04-12 00:00:00';
msg.toDate= '2015-03-12 00:00:00';
msg.payload = "SELECT COL2 FROM DASH104951.TESTDATE WHERE START >= ? AND END <= ?";
return msg;
```

In the `dashDB node` I just have the Parameters Marker text field:

```
msg.fromDate,msg.toDate
```

Everything worked fine.

Here is my node-red flow if you want to import it to your own node-red application:

```
[{"id":"211a834b.dee57c","type":"inject","z":"197f318.fe680ce","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"none","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":117,"y":115,"wires":[["7a23c994.85dc38"]]},{"id":"7a23c994.85dc38","type":"function","z":"197f318.fe680ce","name":"Build Query","func":"msg.fromDate = '2011-04-12 00:00:00';\nmsg.toDate= '2015-03-12 00:00:00';\nmsg.payload = \"SELECT COL2 FROM DASH104951.TESTDATE WHERE START >= ? AND END <= ?\";\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":325,"y":123,"wires":[["559c92e4.aa636c"]]},{"id":"24974090.db68c","type":"debug","z":"197f318.fe680ce","name":"dashDB query result","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"true","x":773,"y":125,"wires":[]},{"id":"559c92e4.aa636c","type":"dashDB in","z":"197f318.fe680ce","service":"dashDB-0a","query":"","params":"msg.fromDate,msg.toDate","name":"","x":548,"y":131,"wires":[["24974090.db68c"]]}]
```

Comment: I'm not using quotes between parameters - it was used only for better formatting my question.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification, hopefully my answer above helped. If not let me know.